# How to install most recent httpuv?

Tags: r, shiny, httpuv

I've downloaded the tar.gz for httpuv but can't read it properly.  I need it to install shiny.

```
install.packages("c:/.../httpuv_1.4.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

produces

> Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f
>   "C:/PROGRA1/R/R-331.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f
>   "C:/PROGRA1/R/R-331.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX1X)
>   $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)'
>   SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)'
>   SHLIB="httpuv.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports-legacy.o RcppExports.o
>   callback.o callbackqueue.o filedatasource-unix.o filedatasource-win.o
>   http.o httprequest.o httpresponse.o httpuv.o md5.o
>   set_invalid_parameter.o socket.o thread.o utils.o uvutil.o
>   webapplication.o websockets-base.o websockets-hixie76.o
>   websockets-hybi03.o websockets-ietf.o websockets.o"' had status 127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you want to install packages containing compiled code from source, you have to install a suitable compiler and tools. On Windows this means installing [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). Afterwards:

```
 install.packages("httpuv", type = "source")
```

should compile and  install the most recent version. However, version 1.4.5 of httpuv is available in binary form on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=httpuv). So installing from source is only needed if you are using an old R version (<= 3.3).